# Carousel fade slide causes white space during transition animation

Tags: carousel, whitespace, transition, fadein, slide

```html
<div id="ca" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
 <div class="carousel-inner" ng-if = "true">
  <div class="item active">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/one.png">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/two.png">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/three.png">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/cfour.png">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/five.png">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/images/six.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.item.active img {
     transition: transform 6000ms linear 0s;
    /* This should be based on your carousel setting. For bs, it should be 5second*/
    /*scale increases the width and height 1.05 times*/
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 5950ms linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 5950ms linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
   25% { opacity:0.50;}
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity:0.50;}
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
    /*opacity: 1;*/
  animation: mktrans 5100ms linear forwards;
}
@keyframes mktrans {
    0% { opacity:1;}
    50% { opacity:0.50;}
    75% { opacity:0.75}
    100% {
    opacity:0;
    }
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
}

.item img{
    max-height: 320px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This code causes a white background on carousel-inner when transitioning. Tried different approaches given in other answers and did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to mod the javascript that controls the carousel itself, essentially you need to tell it to wait a longer time before removing the active component.